X11 forwarding - Putty - Xming: Why app run on the server instead of the client side?
I am trying to understand a few details about X11 forwarding using Putty and Xming.
I have an Ubuntu 24.04 LTS machine and am connecting to it from the same network using Windows 10 with Putty and Xming. I enabled X11 forwarding in Putty and the "X display location" is set to be localhost:0 or left blank with no difference. Everything works great as long as the account I am using is not logged in on the server side. If I logged in to the server with the same credentials funny things started to happen. A few programs (xeyes, xclock, lrfviewer, gimp, and calibre) continue to work without problem. However, if I try to open gedit it will open on the server instead of the client side. Also, LibreOffice shows more interesting results, the splash screen appears on the client, and the program starts to load on the client side, then the program opens on the server side.
Why do some programs run on the server instead of the client side?
What causes that behavior for some programs while other programs aren't affected?
EDIT:
I found more interesting details about gedit behavior, countless workaround that doesn't work, and one solution that forces gedit to open on the client side.
While gedit opens on the server side, if I choose 'About gedit' and press the 'website' link on the server that will cause Chrome to open on the client side. If I press Ctrl + O over Chrome the Open file dialog opens on the server-side. Anything I choose from the dialog box will open on the client side. The only way that forces gedit and LibreOffice to open on the client side is the following commands.
gedit --display ${DISPLAY}

libreoffice --display ${DISPLAY}

I tried both Xming and VcXsrv servers and found no differences in the results.

Something to do with Wayland?


Why do some programs run on the server instead of the client side?

They're not X11 programs.
Gedit is built on the GTK3 toolkit, meaning it is an X11 client and a Wayland client, with the latter being attempted first. If the toolkit successfully connects to a Wayland display server, then it does not use X11 for anything and does not look at the DISPLAY environment variable.

For GTK3 programs, if you want to force X11 to be used, set GDK_BACKEND=x11.

For Qt5/6, the equivalent should be QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb.

For SDL (where it is still the default), use SDL_VIDEODRIVER=x11.

Setting an invalid WAYLAND_DISPLAY= might work for the programs that roll their own.


(For Gedit specifically, note that it tries to work as a "single instance" program and will re-start itself through D-Bus, losing any custom environment variables in the process; you need to add the -s (standalone) option to avoid that.)

They all also run on the server side either way. X11 does not change where the processing happens; it's merely a network graphics protocol that only affects where the windows get displayed.

Great, i had the same issue. I would like to share that after a long search I managed to get it resolved.
On the server side i had entered:
export GDK_BACKEND=x11
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb
export SDL_VIDEODRIVER=x11

In addition, I saw that the server had activated wayland and the client had activated X11. I had wayland disabled in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf on the server.
ssh -X peter@192.168.2.124 gedit -s

It works! Thanks
